# R missForest mixError does no sense?

Tags: missing-data

For the mixError function in missForest, the documentation says
Usage:
mixError(ximp, xmis, xtrue)
Arguments
ximp : imputed data matrix with variables in the columns and observations in the rows. Note there should not be any missing values.
xmis: data matrix with missing values.
xtrue: complete data matrix. Note there should not be any missing values.

Then my question is..
If I have already xtrue, why do I need this function?

All the examples have a complete data, they impute some NA's on purpose, then they use missForest to fill out the NA's and then they calculate the error comparing the imputed data with the original data without NA's.

But.. what is the sense of that? If I already have the complete data!

So, the question is also

Could xtrue be the original data with all the rows with NA's removed??

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: data(iris)
set.seed(81)
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.2)
## Impute missing values using 'missForest':
iris.imp <- missForest(iris.mis)

## Compute the true imputation error manually:
err.imp <- mixError(iris.imp$ximp, iris.mis, iris)


The question is that the 3rd parameter is iris, which is already c complete dataframe.
If we have an inclomplete dataframe (iris.mis) that we complete (iris.imp), but we never have the complete "original" dataset (iris).. then, how can we calculate or approximate the imputation error (err.imp)?